# Correlations of $\phi(n)/n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know that the average of $\phi(n)/n$ is approximated by a constant. Here $\phi $ is the Euler quotient function. One can furthermore show asymptotics with a secondary main term, at least
for the smooth sum
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \frac{\phi(n) } {n} w(n/x)=c_0(w) x+c_1(w) (\log  x ) +o(\log  x ) ,$$ where $w$ is a smooth weight and $c_0,c_1$ are constants depending on $w$.

Can we prove **asymptotics** for the secondary term regarding the shifted sum $$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \frac{\phi(n) } {n}\frac{\phi(n+1) } {n+1} w(n/x) $$ for some $w$? It is not clear to me whether the secondary term here should be oscillating or like $\sim c \log^2 x$ or something else. The standard approach to prove the previous asymptotic relies on the fact that $\frac{\phi(n) } {n} $ is multiplicative, whereas $\frac{\phi(n) } {n}\frac{\phi(n+1) } {n+1}$ is clearly not.

Comment: where could I find the mentioned standard approach to the first asymptotic?, hopefully it would help me to understand more

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01112687/document   Equation (9)

Answer (score 6):

In this answer, we will treat the case when the sum is over $n\leq x$ without the smooth weight function. The asymptotic formula should be suitably adapted to the weight function.

Ingham proved in p.208 (18) of [Some Asymptotic Formulae in the Theory of Numbers](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s1-2.3.202) (Journal of the London Mathematical Society,
V. 1-2, Issue 3, 1927, pp. 202-208).  that the following holds:

$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \phi(n)\phi(n+1) \sim \frac13 A x^3, \ \ (1)
$$

where $A=\prod_p \left(1-\frac2{p^2}\right)$. By partial summation, we have
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\phi(n)}n \frac{\phi(n+1)}{n+1} \sim Ax.  \ \ (2)
$$

However, the derivation of (1) is not written in the paper. The method in the paper is adapted here to derive (2) directly with the secondary term estimate. By $\frac{\phi(n)}n=\sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}d$, we need to estimate the sum
$$
\sum_{\substack{{ms\leq x}\\{lr-ms=1}}}\frac{\mu(l)}l \frac{\mu(m)}m.
$$
Since $lmrs\leq x(x+1)=X^2$, the sum can be written as
$$
\sum_{\substack{{lm\leq X^2}\\{lr-ms=1}\\{s\leq \frac xm}}}\frac{\mu(l)}l \frac{\mu(m)}m.
$$
The condition $lr-ms=1$ restricts integers $l$ and $m$ into $(l,m)=1$, $s$ in single congruence modulo $l$, and $r$ is uniquely determined depending on $s$. Thus, it is enough to consider the sum
$$
\sum_{\substack{{lm\leq X^2}\\{(l,m)=1}}}\frac{\mu(l)}l \frac{\mu(m)}m\left(\frac x{ml} + O(1)\right).
$$
The error term $O(1)$ contributes at most $O(\log^2 X)$. The condition $(l,m)=1$ is treated with inserting $\sum_{d|l, d|m}\mu(d)$ into the sum. Then the main term without $x$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{d^2uv\leq X^2} &\frac{\mu(d)}{d^4}\frac{\mu(du)}{u^2}\frac{\mu(dv)}{v^2}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq X} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^4} \sum_{uv\leq \frac{X^2}{d^2}} \frac{\mu(du)}{u^2}\frac{\mu(dv)}{v^2}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq X} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^4} \sum_{u\leq \frac{X^2}{d^2}} \frac{\mu(du)}{u^2} \sum_{v\leq \frac{X^2}{ud^2}} \frac{\mu(dv)}{v^2}\\
&=\sum_{d\leq X} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^4} \sum_{u\leq \frac{X^2}{d^2}}\frac{\mu(du)}{u^2} \left( \frac{\mu(d)\prod_{p|d}\left(1-\frac1{p^2}\right)^{-1}}{\zeta(2)}+O\left(\frac{ud^2}{X^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq X} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^4} \sum_{u\leq \frac{X^2}{d^2}} \frac{\mu(du)}{u^2} \frac{\mu(d)\prod_{p|d}\left(1-\frac1{p^2}\right)^{-1}}{\zeta(2)}+O\left(\frac{\log X}{X^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d\leq X} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^4}\left(\frac{\mu(d)\prod_{p|d}\left(1-\frac1{p^2}\right)^{-1}}{\zeta(2)} \right)^2 + O\left( \frac1{X^2}\right)+O\left(\frac{\log X}{X^2}\right)\\
&=\prod_p \left(1-\frac2{p^2}\right) + O\left(\frac1{X^3}\right)+O\left( \frac1{X^2}\right)+O\left(\frac{\log X}{X^2}\right)\\
&=\prod_p \left(1-\frac2{p^2}\right)+O\left(\frac{\log X}{X^2}\right).
\end{align}
$$
Hence, we obtain the secondary term estimated by $O(\log^2 x)$, yielding
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\phi(n)}n \frac{\phi(n+1)}{n+1} = Ax + O(\log^2 x).
$$

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't answer my question though, which was for an **asymptotic** for the secondary term, not a bound for it.

Comment: You are right. It seems very difficult to find asymptotic for the second term. This is because the error term depends on a particular solution to $lr-ms=1$.

Comment: I think the error term might be oscillating for the unsmoothed sum, so something like $\Omega(\log^2 x )$. Perhaps the smoothed version however gives $\sim c_2 \log^2 x $.

Answer (score 6):

If $w$ is smooth and compactly supported in $[1/2,2]$, say, then
$$\sum_{n}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}\frac{\varphi(n+1)}{n+1}w(n/x) = Cx + O_A((\log x)^{-A}).$$
Write
$$\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = \sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}$$
and
$$\frac{\varphi(n+1)}{n+1} = \sum_{e \mid n+1} \frac{\mu(e)}{e},$$
then interchange the orders of summation. Perform Poisson summation on the $n$ variable to turn the sum into something like
$$\sum_d \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \sum_{(e,d)=1}\frac{\mu(e)}{e} \frac{x}{d^2e^2}\sum_{|k|\leq de/x} e\left(-k\frac{\overline{d}}{e}\right)\widehat{w}(kx/de),$$
where $\overline{d}$ denotes the inverse of $d$ modulo $e$. The $k=0$ term gives the main term, which is seen to be $Cx + O_A((\log x)^{-A})$ by using the cancellation in the mobius function.

The nonzero frequencies contribute an error of size $O_A((\log x)^{-A})$. For these terms, break $d$ and $e$ into dyadic ranges $d \asymp D, e \asymp E$. Clearly we may assume $DE \gg x$. Also, we may assume without loss of generality that $E \ll D$, otherwise use the reciprocity relation
$$\frac{\overline{d}}{e} + \frac{\overline{e}}{d}\equiv \frac{1}{de}\pmod{1}$$
to switch $d$ and $e$ in the exponential. After some work, Siegel-Walfisz and the large sieve cover the case when $E\leq D (\log x)^{-B}$, so we may assume $D \approx E$. The double sum over $d$ and $e$ may then be suitably bounded using results of Duke-Friedlander-Iwaniec on [bilinear forms in Kloosterman fractions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002220050135) (see also work of [Bettin and Chandee](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870815304965)).

[Edit: March 15]

I'm adding a bit more detail, as requested. I'm assuming the smoothing $w$ is a smooth bump function, so the Fourier transform satisfies $|\widehat{w}(y)| \ll \exp(-|y|^{1/2})$, say. The arguments below might have to be adapted or substituted entirely for less smooth weights.

With $w$ as above, one finds that
$$\sum_n \varphi(n)/n w(n/x) = Cx + O_A((\log x)^{-A})$$
by Mellin inversion, contour shifting, and the zero-free region for zeta.

Now, as to the correlation sum. Begin as above, and perform Poisson summation. We separate the $k=0$ term which gives the main term, and the contribution of the nonzero frequencies is
$$\sum_{d\ll x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\sum_{\substack{e \ll x \\ (e,d)=1}}\frac{\mu(e)}{e}\frac{x}{de}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}} e\left(-k\frac{\overline{d}}{e}\right) \widehat{w}\left(k\frac{x}{de} \right).$$
Dyadically decompose $d\asymp D$ and $e \asymp E$. As mentioned above, up to changing the sign of $k$ in the exponential one may assume that $E \ll D$ by using reciprocity.

Now use the rapid decay of $\widehat{w}$ to truncate the sum on $k$. Up to a minor change in the coefficients and an acceptable error term, we have
$$\frac{x}{D^2E^2}\sum_{e\asymp E} \mu(e) \sum_{\substack{d \asymp D \\ (d,e)=1}}\mu(d) \sum_{0<|k|\leq (\log x)^{10}DE/x} e\left(k\frac{\overline{d}}{e}\right)e\left(\frac{k}{de} \right) \widehat{w}\left(k\frac{x}{de} \right).$$
Clearly, we may assume $DE > x(\log x)^{-11}$, say.

We are going to use the large sieve inequality, but in order to do so we need to separate the $d$ and $e$ variables from each other inside $\widehat{w}$. Change variables in the definition of $\widehat{w}$ and interchange to obtain
$$\int_{u \asymp 1} \frac{x}{D^2E^2}\sum_{0<|k|\leq (\log x)^{10}DE/x} \sum_{e \asymp E}\mu(e)w(\tfrac{eu}{E})\sum_{\substack{d \asymp D \\ (d,e)=1}}\mu(d) e\left(-k\frac{x}{dE}u \right)  e\left(-k\frac{\overline{d}}{e}\right) du,$$
where this holds up to harmless changes in the $d$ and $e$ coefficients. We work uniformly in $u\asymp 1$, so we can drop the integral.

We give two arguments. The first works when $E$ is a bit smaller than $D$, and the other works when they are about the same size.

The first argument uses the large sieve. Split the sum over $d$ into arithmetic progressions modulo $e$ to separate the additive character, then apply multiplicative characters to detect the congruence condition modulo $e$. This turns the sum over $d$ into
$$\frac{1}{\varphi(e)}\sum_{\chi (e)}\sum_{(a,e)=1}e\left(-k\frac{\overline{a}}{e}\right) \overline{\chi}(a)\sum_{\substack{d \asymp D}}\mu(d)\chi(d) e\left(-k\frac{x}{dE}u \right).$$
We take out the contribution of the principal character $\chi_0 \pmod{e}$. We get cancellation in the sum over $d$ using partial summation. The sum over $a\pmod{e}$ becomes a Ramanujan sum, which has size $\leq (|k|,e)$, the GCD of $|k|$ and $e$. It is easy to see that the total contribution from $\chi_0$ after summing over all the variables is $\ll_A (\log x)^{-A}$.

We have to bound the contribution of the non-principal characters:
$$\frac{x}{D^2E^2}\sum_{0<|k|\leq (\log x)^{10}DE/x} \sum_{e \asymp E}\mu(e)w(\tfrac{eu}{E})\frac{1}{\varphi(e)}\sum_{\substack{\chi (e) \\ \chi \neq \chi_0}}\sum_{(a,e)=1}e\left(-k\frac{\overline{a}}{e}\right) \overline{\chi}(a)\sum_{\substack{d \asymp D}}\mu(d)\chi(d) e\left(-k\frac{x}{dE}u \right).$$
We fixed $k$, since we will not need to sum over this variable, and then apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the sum over $e$. This gives
$$\sum_e \ll (\Sigma_1 \Sigma_2)^{1/2},$$
where
$$\Sigma_1 = \sum_{e \asymp E} \frac{1}{\varphi(e)}\sum_{\substack{\chi (e) \\ \chi \neq \chi_0}} \left|\sum_{(a,e)=1}e\left(-k\frac{\overline{a}}{e}\right) \overline{\chi}(a) \right|^2$$
and
$$\Sigma_2 = \sum_{e \asymp E} \frac{1}{\varphi(e)}\sum_{\substack{\chi (e) \\ \chi \neq \chi_0}} \left|\sum_{\substack{d \in I_D}}\mu(d)\chi(d) e\left(-k\frac{x}{dE}u \right) \right|^2.$$
We easily bound $\Sigma_1$ by using positivity to include $\chi_0$, then opening the square and using orthogonality of characters. It follows that
$$\Sigma_1 \ll E^2.$$

The argument for $\Sigma_2$ is slightly more involved. First, we reduce to summing over primitive Dirichlet characters $\psi$ (cf. any standard proof of the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem). We apply a dyadic decomposition to the conductor of the primitive characters, so we derive something like
$$\Sigma_2 \ll \sum_{1 \ll R = 2^j\ll E}\sum_{f \ll E} \frac{1}{\varphi(f)}\sum_{r \asymp R} \frac{1}{\varphi(r)} \sum_{\substack{\psi( r) \\ \psi \text{ prim}}}\Big|\sum_{\substack{d \in I_D \\ (d,f)=1}}\mu(d)\psi(d) e\left(-k\frac{x}{dE}u \right) \Big|^2.$$
If $R \leq (\log x)^C$ then we use partial summation and the Siegel-Walfisz theorem to bound the sum over $d$. If $R > (\log x)^C$ we use the multiplicative large sieve inequality
$$\sum_{r \asymp R} \frac{1}{\varphi(r)} \sum_{\substack{\psi( r) \\ \psi \text{ prim}}}\Big|\sum_{\substack{d \in I_D \\ (d,f)=1}}\mu(d)\psi(d) c(d)e\left(-k\frac{x}{dE}u \right) \Big|^2 \ll \frac{1}{R}\left(R^2 + D \right)D.$$
We deduce that
$$\Sigma_2 \ll D^2 (\log x)^{-2A} + DE.$$

Recalling the application of Cauchy-Schwarz and the bounds for $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, we sum over $k$ to see that the total contribution is
$$\ll (\log x)^{-A + O(1)} + (\log x)^{O(1)} \left(\frac{E}{D} \right)^{1/2}.$$
This is acceptably small if $E \leq D(\log x)^{-B}$.

Therefore, we may assume that $D x^{-o(1)} \ll E \ll D$. Since $DE \gg x^{1-o(1)}$ this implies $D \gg x^{1/2-o(1)}$. For this second argument we do not need any properties of the coefficients attached to the $d$ and $e$ variables other than that they are 1-bounded, so we wish to get a bound on
$$\frac{x}{D^2E^2}\sum_{1\leq k\leq (\log x)^{10}DE/x}\Big| \mathop{\sum\sum}_{\substack{d \asymp D \\ e \asymp E \\ (d,e)=1}}\alpha_d \beta_e e \left(k \frac{\overline{d}}{e} \right)\Big|$$
for 1-bounded coefficients $\alpha_d,\beta_e$. Theorem 2 of the above-mentioned Duke-Friedlander-Iwaniec paper gives
$$\Big| \mathop{\sum\sum}_{\substack{d \asymp D \\ e \asymp E \\ (d,e)=1}}\alpha_d \beta_e e \left(k \frac{\overline{d}}{e} \right)\Big| \ll (DE)^{1/2} (k+DE)^{3/8} (D+E)^{11/48}\ll D^{2-1/48+o(1)},$$
which saves $D^{1/48}$ over the trivial bound. Therefore
$$\frac{x}{D^2E^2}\sum_{1\leq k\leq (\log x)^{10}DE/x}\Big| \mathop{\sum\sum}_{\substack{d \asymp D \\ e \asymp E \\ (d,e)=1}}\alpha_d \beta_e e \left(k \frac{\overline{d}}{e} \right)\Big| \ll \frac{D^{2 - \frac{1}{48} + o(1)}}{DE} \ll D^{-1/48+o(1)} \ll x^{-1/96+o(1)}.$$

Comment: That is great, many thanks! I was wondering why there is no secondary term here but there is a secondary term in the simpler sum $\sum_{n\leq x } \phi(n)/n w(n/x)$? Is it because of exponential sums machinery?

Comment: @Dr.Pi I think the secondary term of $\sum_{n\leq x} \phi(n)/n w(n/x)$ might be $c_1(w) \log x$ and error is $o(\log x)$. You wrote $\log^2 x$ in your post.

Comment: @AofE I am wondering about the same thing. I will be great if you can elaborate on Poisson summation part, how Siegel-Walfisz and large sieve work here, and how to use DFI result. The current best error term on unsmoothed sum $\sum_{n\leq x} \phi(n)/n$ has $O(\log^{2/3} x (\log\log x)^{4/3})$.

Comment: @Sungjin Kim : indeed you are right, I corrected it-thank you for the comment.